# Change integer days into a default date format YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: r, date

I'm fairly new to R and I have been given data that is accumulated by days as an integer and need to interpret into a YYYY/MM/DD format.

For example

```
X <- c(77221,77448,77455)
```

I know that "77221" means 31/05/12.

I have tried using:

```
as.Date.POSIXct(X, origin = "2012-10-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d",  tz= "GMT")
```

However, I'm getting the following message:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

Any ideas how can I make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried running this within your RConsole? x <- as.POSIXct('2012-05-31 12:15'); unclass(x)

x comes out to be 1338446700

Comment: Some of the statements in your question are nonsense. Your origin is 5 months after day 77221.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "77221" corresponds to 31/05/12, then the origin is "1800-12-28":

```
as.Date("2012-05-31") - 77221
# [1] "1800-12-28"

format(as.Date(c(77221, 77448, 77455), origin="1800-12-28"), "%Y/%m/%d")
# [1] "2012/05/31" "2013/01/13" "2013/01/20"
```

Comment: Excel on Windows uses 1800-12-30 as the origin so I wonder if the poster of the question made an error and meant to say that 77221 corresponds to 2012-06-02?

Comment: Im gonna try this one, it looks very logical! thanks!

Comment: It worked! thanks this help me understand the data that has been given to me!